# JPA not saving entity: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm having problems with persisting a one-to-many, many-to-one bi-directional relationship to my database and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong exactly. Hope that someone can help me further.

I have 2 entities in my database declared as follows:

```
class Lot {
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Request.class, mappedBy = "lot", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Requests> requests;
}

class Request{
    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_lot")
    private Lot lot;
}
```

the problem comes here:

```
class RequestManagerImpl{
    // compose Request r object
    requestId = saveRequest(r).getId();

    // check to see if we need to create a parent object
    LotType lot = createRequestInput.getLot();
    if(lot != null){
        addRequestToLot(Lists.newArrayList(r), lot);
    }
}

class LotManagerImpl {
    @Override
    public Lot addRequestsToLot(List<Request> requests, Lot lot) {

        if (lot != null && requests != null && !requests.isEmpty()) {
            for (Request request : requests) {
            lot.addRequest(request);
        }
        Lot lotValue = lotDAO.saveOrUpdate(lot);
        if (lotValue != null) {
            updateLotStatusByRequestsStatus(lotValue);
        }
        return lotValue;
    }
} 
class LotDAO {
    @Override
    public Lot saveOrUpdate(Lot lot) {
        if (em.contains(lot)) {
            em.merge(lot);
        } else {
            em.persist(lot);
        }
        return lot;
    }
}
class RequestDAO {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    Request saveRequest(Request request);
}
```

The em.persist returns me the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: disp.entities.Request
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:771)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:491)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:765)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at .proxy.$Proxy78.persist(Unknown Source)
    at disp.dao.impl.LotDAOImpl.saveOrUpdate(LotDAOImpl.java:123)
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: How are managing your transaction ?? is it managed by your container, or are your application responsible your this ??

Comment: Show the real code. Your `addRequestsToLot` takes 2 parameters, but you're calling it with one. Do you understand what the error means?

Comment: You're also supposed to include the stacktrace or at least the line where the exception happens. It's not enough to just dump a pile of code that's not even the real code you're running, and expect us to fix things for you.

Comment: i've updated my code. This is the basic logic it follows, I've left all the business logic out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing the magic of the oneToMany mapping here

The line
`requestId = saveRequest(r).getId();` is not possible because of it's dependency to the Lot.

If you add the Request to the Lot and save the Lot, the request is automatically saved as a result of the Mapping.

Comment: What's certain in my scenario is that I need to persist a request object. A lot optionally be created as a parent object of the Request.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the problem myself.

The problem was in the RequestDAO:: saveRequest method were the transaction was declared as Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW. This was creating the request (child object) in a new transaction and later on detaching from the Lot (parent) when saving it.

I simply had to change it to Propagation.REQUIRED to use the existing transaction to commit both the parent and the child object.